# Ionic side menu not displaying

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am attempting to add in a side menu in my ionic project. I've viewed the Ionic framework docs and the API, but even with that help I still can't get it to show. This is my html code:

```
    <ion-menu [content]="content" side="right" persistent="true">
        <ion-header>
            <ion-toolbar>
                <ion-title>
                    Menu
                </ion-title>
            </ion-toolbar>
        </ion-header>

        <ion-content>
            <ion-list>
                <button ion-item>
                    Home
                </button>
                <button ion-item>
                    Friends/Collaborators
                </button>
                <button ion-item>
                    Plans: In Progress
                </button>
                <button ion-item>
                    Plans: Completed
                </button>
                <button ion-item>
                    Plans: Past Events
                </button>
                <button ion-item>
                    Ideas
                </button>
            </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>

    <ion-nav id="nav" #content ></ion-nav>
```

I haven't added in click functions yet; I'm more focused on getting the menu to display first.

Comment: Create a test project with the `sidemenu` template and see how it works : `ionic start myTestProject sidemenu`

Comment: The test project worked... I'm going to try to use that for guidance and see if there's any differences between the test project and my project

Comment: UPDATE: I integrated the side menu template code with my already-created project and the side menu is now working.

Comment: @A.Stinson Welcome to SO. add your finding as answer or remove your question if not relevant anymroe please